# JavaScript Array and jQuery inArray causing problems with first array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Basically, here is a dummy version of the code I'm using and I'll explain what is happening:

```
var types = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4', 'type5'],
    type = 'type1';

if ($.inArray(type, types)) {
    alert('In Array');
} else {
    alert('Not In Array');
}
```

It's coming up with it not being in the array, whereas if I change the `type` value to 'type2' or any other value that's in the array it says it's in the array. Now if I add a blank value at the start of the array like this:

```
var types = ['', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4', 'type5']
```

Put the `type` value back to 'type1' it now tells me it's in the array. I'm probably missing something obvious, I'm not sure ha. But I'm just a little confused as to why it doesn't accept that it's the first in the array when the first array value is an actual value? If anyone could shed some light on to this it would be appreciated!

Comment: The confusingly named `$.inArray` method returns an index, not a boolean. The index `0` is falsey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually check for `-1` when using $.inArray, otherwise the first index will return `0`, which is falsy

```
if ($.inArray(type, types) != -1) {
    alert('In Array');
} else {
    alert('Not In Array');
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Will mark as top answer when it allows me to!

Answer (score 1):

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf()
>   method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the
>   first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/